# symfony2 get command line executed

Tags: php, symfony

I am creating a console command in symfony2. I need to log an executed line i run. How to get that line?

So if i run:

```
php app/console my-command fileName.txt --myoption=100
```

I want to get value "php app/console my-command fileName.txt --myoption=100"

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm interpreting the question as: Within the Command code itself, you want to determine what was written on the command line in order to end up executing that Symfony Command?

If that's correct, then I don't think it's possible to get it exactly. However, you should be able to get [almost?] the same effect by doing this:

```
implode(" ", $_SERVER['argv'])
```

Example:

```
class SomeCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {       
        $output->writeln( implode(" ", $_SERVER['argv']) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Better solution would be to use `$input->__toString()`

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->info(\sprintf('Executing %s', $input->__toString()));
}
```

Comment: Not all classes that implement `InputInterface` have the magic `__toString` method set...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at ArgvInput class you might notice that argv values are holded in private property without any getter. Basically it means you can't access to this information. Of course you may use $_SERVER['argv'] directly but this is not very pretty solution.

So, it seems that there is no "clean" or "easy" way to achieve exactly what you want.

However you have access to every information that you need.

```
$this->getName(); // gets name of command (eg. "my-comand")
$input->getArguments(); // gets all arguments (eg. "fileName.txt")
$input->getOptions(); // get all options (eg. --myoption => 100)
```

You can put it together to one string. But this is after validation, so if you need log bad commands as well (I mean with wrong parameters and so on) this doesn't pass exam.

Comment: this also can be a solution. Thanks

Comment: For future references, from Symfony3 was introduced a __toString() method in the ArgvInput class : https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/3.0/Input/ArgvInput.php#L328 ; It returns exactly what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Symfony Request object.

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
foreach ($request->server->get('argv') as $arg) {
 echo $arg;
}
```